# get Squid proxy server authentication type from local client

Tags: debian, proxy, authentication, squid, ntlm

Just like the title is:

Is there a way to get the authentication type of a squid proxyserver from a client in the local network?

Im using debian

UPDATE 1:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Server: squid/3.3.9
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 17:51:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3305
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="Squid Web Proxy"
X-Cache: MISS from domain.com
Via: 1.1 domain.com (squid/3.3.9)
Connection: keep-alive
```

I am only seeing the Basic realm line. So my Proxy only accepts Basic authentication right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is inspect the HTTP response headers of a 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) response from your proxy.  It should include the authentication schemes that it will accept from a client.  You'll see something like this, one header for each scheme:

```
Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="SomeRealm"
```

Based on your edit yes, your proxy won't accept NTLM authentication.  Since there is just the one Proxy-Authenticate header for Basic, then your clients will only send Basic authentication.  It seems your proxy is not configured (or at least properly) to accept anything other than basic authentication.

Comment: @Ferris see my edit

Comment: @Ferris If an application doesn't support proxies then your only option is to get creative with your routing.  This involves something like setting the default route to be the IP of the internal interface of the firewall, or installing multiple interfaces on the client and binding them to different networks.  Either way, it's a drag.